# When jenkins must be restarted?

Tags: jenkins

What are the scenarios when jenkins must be restarted. Right now, I am setting up jenkins. And, I am facing lots of issues like permission denied, no such file or directory etc. So, once I install new command used by my build process, do I need to restart jenkins? If I change any environment variable, change ownership of the file, do I need to restart jenkins?

Comment: Jenkins run with "jenkins" user account, make sure that workspace should be in JENKINS_HOME directory having jenkins:jenkins ownership.

Comment: Yes, it is setup like that.

Comment: To add more: Recently I am trying to do "Automanage webhooks" in jinkins for managing webhooks on Github repo. What I found is, only after restarting Jenkins, it creates respective webhook on Github repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting permissions errors, I would ensure that the user running Jenkins has read/write access to the directory/file that you're trying to modify. Make sure that this user also owns the JENKINS_HOME directory.

Typically, Jenkins shouldn't need to be restarted in any of the situations that you stated.

If you post more details about what you're trying to do, I'm sure people here can help.